# How to calculate time diferences PHP?

Tags: php

I have this data:
$t1 = '75:00'; //Corresponds to Hours:Minutes
$t2 = '05:13';

// I need to know the time diference in this example must return:
'69:47'

Comment: Here is a post that could be useful for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: 75:00 is not a valid time. Seperate it. `list($min, $sec) = explode(':', $t1);`. Then you can turn it all into seconds, diff that and calc back to minutes and seconds.

Comment: Something this simple doesn’t need a massive amount of date functions thrown at it, you can do the minimal amount of math required yourself … https://3v4l.org/O24qT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

75:00 is not a valid time, but if you found yourself in a situation that you have to use that, use this code below

```
<?php


function convertToMinutes($time)
{

    list($hour, $minutes) = explode(":", $time);
    $hoursToMinutes = $hour * 60;
    $addMinutes = $hoursToMinutes + $minutes;
    return $addMinutes;
}

function convertToHours($time)
{
    $hours = floor($time / 60);
    $minutes = $time % 60;

    if ($time < 60) {
        return $time;
    }
    return $hours . ":" . $minutes;
}

function timeDifference($time1, $time2)
{
    if ($time1 >= $time2) {
        $diff = convertToMinutes($time1) - convertToMinutes($time2);

        return convertToHours($diff);
    }
    $diff = convertToMinutes($time2) - convertToMinutes($time1);
    return convertToHours($diff);
}

$t1 = '75:00';
$t2 = '05:13';

$answer = timeDifference($t1, $t2);

echo $answer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to calculate time difference -

```
$t1 = new DateTime('23:00');
$t2 = new DateTime('05:13');
$interval = $t1->diff($t2);
echo $interval->format("%H:%i");
```

*75:00 is not a valid time. You have to take care of that.

Comment: Yes I know that and this is my problem... I think the best solution it's divide by days, and finaly add the hours... ?

Comment: Yeah, go with that. @JoseRuiz

Comment: Time here means duration. And, you're right, it isn't a valid time of the day, so you cannot use date functions since they'll typically wrap around at 24 hours (or 23 or 25 if you hit DST boundaries).